# Efficiency on displaying random authors based on large database

Tags: database, users, performance

I'm trying to display a list of 5 authors **randomly**. Here are some solutions I had found:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502609/get-authors-randomly
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91326/1044

I'm currently using the former solution except that I use `WP_User_Query` like so:

```
$args  = array(
    'role' => 'subscriber'
);
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Shuffle list to get random results
shuffle($authors);
```

However, to my *amateurish* understanding, this **will fetch the whole list of users**. So I'm just wondering if I had around **2000-5000 users (or more)**, will this affect **page load** drastically? how can I make this more efficient?

**UPDATE:**

Also would `array_rand()` be a more efficient method compare to `shuffle()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are concerned about efficiency, you might want to use the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to store the query. Storing something that you want to randomize might seem counter-intuitive, but if you store the entire query, you can always randomize and manipulate the resulting array to get the results you want.

Here's how to get all the subscribers and store them in a transient, with a but of straight PHP at the end to shuffle/randomize the result and then pick off the first 5 results using [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
if ( false === ( $users = get_transient( 'get_all_subscribers' ) ) ) {
     // this code runs when there is no valid transient set

    $args  = array(
        'role'   => 'subscriber'
    );

    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    $users = $wp_user_query->get_results();

    set_transient( 'get_all_subscribers', $users );
}

// proceed with data normally
// randomize the stored result
shuffle( $users );
$rand_users = array_slice( $users, 0, 5 );

var_dump( $rand_users );
```

and then to make sure the transient is up to date, we'll delete it when a user is updated or added:

```
// Create a simple function to delete our transient
function delete_all_subscribers_transient() {
     delete_transient( 'get_all_subscribers' );
}
// Add the function to the profile_update and user_registration hooks
add_action( 'profile_update', 'delete_all_subscribers_transient' );
add_action( 'user_register', 'delete_all_subscribers_transient' );
```

Comment: Does this randomize the list with every page refresh?

Comment: Did you try it? `shuffle()` is outside the transient, so it should.

Comment: Just wondering, will 'shuffling' the entire query every time the page is viewed affect page load? (Sorry for the amateurish question)

Comment: It's not amateurish, but you'd have to actual run some benchmark tests to compare, and I don't know how to do that either.  I'd wager that shuffling an array is a lot more efficient than running a custom query on every page load.

Comment: You could shuffle `$users` when the transient is created and then use a random starting point for the `array_slice`. Then you are only shuffling once.

Comment: Or you could do that. It seems less random since the order is the same, just the start is varied, but it might be random enough for the purpose. If you tried to start 2-from-the-end, and wanted to select 5, do you know if `array_slice` will wrap around? Or will it only return 2?

Comment: It will not wrap, but you could add the first four to the end of the array and get the same effect. You could also shuffle the array of 5. You could also leave the original array alone and, using `count()`, select 5 random indexes. The only problem is making sure you do not randomly select the same index more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to fetch all users if you only need `5`.

If you want to use `WP_User_Query()` to fetch 5 users by random, you can try to use the `pre_user_query` hook to overwrite the *orderby* part:

```
$args  = array(
    'role'   => 'subscriber',
    'number' => 5,
);
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_pre_user_query' );
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

where

```
function my_pre_user_query( $q ){
    $q->query_orderby = ' ORDER BY RAND() ';

    // remove the hook
    remove_action( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
}
```

### Update:

This [article](http://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/) contains a trick to cut down the number of rows, using a special 
`WHERE` condition, before the `ORDER BY RAND()` kicks in ... as far as I understand it.

The `WHERE` condition in your case might be

```
WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((5/COUNT(*))*10) FROM wp_users)
```

So if you have a very large number of users, then you could try out this modified action callback:

```
function my_pre_user_query( $q ){
    $q->query_where = str_replace( 'WHERE 1=1', 'WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((5/COUNT(*))*10) FROM wp_users) ', $q->query_where );
    $q->query_orderby = ' ORDER BY RAND() ';

    // remove hook
    remove_action( current_filter() , __FUNCTION__ );
}
```

if the trick from the above article is working!

Here is a more general version of the modified callback:

```
function my_pre_user_query( $q ){

    $limit = preg_replace( '/[^\d]/', '', $q->query_limit );

    $from   = 'WHERE 1=1';
    $to     = sprintf( 'WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((%d/COUNT(*))*10) FROM %susers)', 
                        $limit, 
                        $GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix 
             );

    $q->query_where   = str_replace( $from, $to, $q->query_where );
    $q->query_orderby = ' ORDER BY RAND() ';

    // remove the hook    
    remove_action( current_filter() , __FUNCTION__ );
}
```

Comment: You can give the $args a `query_id` parameter that you can then look for conditionally in the `my_user_query` instead of having to `remove_action`.

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks for pointing out that method

Comment: I don't think I knew you could remove the action from within itself. Neat. Many ways to do the same thing.

Comment: This works well but I heard that `RAND()` is inefficient for large tables. Found this tips [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/msyql-alternative-order-by-rand/) but not really sure yet how to implement it. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, but always do some benchmarks on your own system to test ;-) [This article](http://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/) gives a nice trick on how to speed things up using an alternative `ORDER BY RAND()` method.