# Improving WP_Query for performance when random posts are ordered

Tags: posts, wp-query, query, query-posts, performance

I have made a new query after I've asked a question about my query_posts code... you guys didn't find that great, so I decided to change that.

I made this:

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$rand = new WP_Query("showposts=10&orderby=rand&paged=$page"); 
while($rand->have_posts()) : $rand->the_post();
```

My question is: how can I improve this?

Isn't it better to use an array? So the same code, with an array or not?

So like this:

```
$rand = new WP_Query( array(
    'showposts' => '10',
    'orderby' => rand
) );
```

Would this make my performance better?

And I read something about adding:

```
'update_post_meta_cache' => false
```

To improve the performance if terms are not going to be used. My question: what are terms anyway? Are they trying to say tags and / or categories with this?

**Edit:**

```
function random_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && !$query->is_paged() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

What if I would use this? Do I have to change my WP_Query or do I have to remove it? I don't get what `pre_get_posts` does actually.

Comment: If you're worried about the impact on server, I would recommend to order queried objects randomly in front-end _via_ `JS` and let the browser/user's device take the hit _(1 person with single device vs 1000 or 10 000 people with one server - that's a big difference)_. Obviously there are limitations like with everything. `JS` is super fast but it's limitations are set by user's device.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate that thought. Have to it with PHP, for now, though.

Comment: Is this pre-optimization or is this random query currently slowing down your site? Do you see much difference compared to e.g. date ordering? [Here's my answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144662/26350) for an alternative random ordering, that I based on an [article](https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/) by Josh Hartman, that might or might not work for you?

Comment: It isn't slowing it down very much, but I read that WP Query by defaults adds 5 queries in comparison to query_posts for example. So I assumed that this could be done quicker. Thanks for your post btw, I will check that out as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with orderby rand is that on most setups the database will load all posts into memory, then randomly order them, and return what you asked for. It's that loading into memory that makes the query super slow/expensive

Also yes, terms are individual categories and tags, where category is a taxonomy, and the 'development' category is a term in that taxonomy.

Finally, your initial code snippet implies you're using a page template or attempting to override what's shown on the page. This is bad as it discards the main query and launches a second query. The cost of the first query still occurs, but it's discarded so it's a waste of time. This is why `query_posts` is considered harmful, replacing it with a custom `WP_Query` loop doesn't fix that. Consider using `pre_get_posts` instead to intercept the main query and change it

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks for the answer, but it does not answer my questions... I get it that it's even better to avoid WP_Query and use something else instead, but what about the array question? How can I optimize the code I have beside changing WP_Query? And once again: I get your point, but I need a different answer for this one.

Comment: Actually you convinced me to use pre_get_posts, but I don't get the logic. Does my WP_Query have to stay the same? Or do I have to add something to functions.php and remove my WP_Query fully?

Comment: The problem is not which function you used to create the second query, it's that you created a second query at all. Using `pre_get_posts` lets you modify the original query rather than making a second. As for using an array versus a string, the difference in performance is miniscule and a waste of your time to even think about, but go for an array, as that's what it's using internally, and it's much easier to read

Comment: Also, using pre_get_posts doesn't make your random order query any faster, it just reduces the number of queries you're making and simplifies your templates. ordering by random is still inherently expensive and you should look for an alternative

Comment: I get it. Thank you! Last question: how should I use pre_get_posts? Is it an additional function where my WP_Query has to stay like it is or do I have to change that as well?

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is a filter, it'll let you intercept the arguments for the main query before the query happens, letting you change it. I recommend you look up the codex entry and read through ( btw these questions would all be good questions to ask on this site, by asking them in comments you're depriving yourself of better answers and reputation for bounties and priviledges ).

Comment: The point of using `pre_get_posts` is that you can avoid using `WP_Query`, aka the second query. It's like asking WordPress to go the shop and bring back a hot chocolate, then waiting. When WordPress comes back, you throw the hot chocolate on the floor and scream "I ACTUALLY WANTED A LATTE", and send it back out, then wait. When WordPress comes back with a latte you complain it took a long time. That's what you're doing when you don't use the main loop and rely on `WP_Query` or `query_posts` to display everything. Better to say the right thing in the first place

Comment: I get it, thank you very much. I will probably ask a new question about how to change my WP_Query to this pre_get_posts query. I appreciate this, merci. And yes, you are right about depriving myself (and others) by asking question in comments.

Comment: Of note, pre_get_posts isn't a query, and you shouldn't think of it that way. It's a way to change what the main query retrieves, it's not a new query. When using it, you should use a standard loop, not a custom WP_Query loop, e.g. `while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ... }` etc. Also don't forget you can mark my answer as correct

Comment: I have a while statement, but I'll show you in a different question. Thanks mate, appreciated.

Comment: Is this still a thing? So, orderby=rand is still super slow and thus not good for performance purposes?

Comment: it's not a WordPress thing, it's a database thing, particularly a MariaDB/MySQL thing. For it to change you would need to see major changes to their database internals that cater for it, which is highly unlikely. You cannot make the query faster if you use `orderby` set to `RAND`, Ordering randomly via the database is fundamentally slow in an unavoidable way, and may always be super slow

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the prompt answer, Tom. I'll just keep the most recent posts instead, in that case.

Comment: if the goal is to show the user something new then you don't need to make the database copy the entire table into memory, randomly re-order it, then perform the rest of your query on the temporary table. You could just pick a random date in PHP and ask for the first 4 posts after that date then shuffle them. Randomness in PHP is cheap, and there isn't really such a thing as random anyway. E.g. true randomness might return the same post 4 times but most people would be unhappy with that result, they usually what they actually want is an even-ish spread so they don't have to pick a criteria

Comment: Thanks for that, Tom. I did not know that we could do it like that. Will check that out, some time. Merci!